# Пожалуйста объясните как работать с websocket в okhttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Я нашёл пример, но он не сильно отличается от остальных примеров найденных в сети. https://youtu.be/Zj4Y6Q2QzNU

Мой код вот так выглядит:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private OkHttpClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://echo.websocket.org").build();
        EchoWebsocket echolistener = new EchoWebsocket();
        WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, echolistener);
        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    }

    class EchoWebsocket extends WebSocketListener {
        private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;

        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
            webSocket.send("Hello, it's cheerful");
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, "Bye!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            super.onMessage(webSocket, text);
            Log.d("SOCKET", "receive " + text);
        }
    }
}
```

По сути тут выполняется единоразовый запрос на сервер через сокет, а сервер отвечает, отправляя этот текст обратно нам. Если я правильно понял.

У меня этот код работает. Но я не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы приложение могло установить один раз соединение и принимать и отправлять сообщения, не разрывая это соединение.

Может кто-то сможет разжевать подробно на примере, как это работает? Я имею в виду, чтобы сообщения отправлять в любой момент времени и принимать их, пока открыто соединение веб сокета.

(Заранее извиняюсь если моя формулировка очень примитивная)

Comment: Вот [хорошая статья](https://stfalcon.com/ru/blog/post/android-websocket).

Comment: Ну собственно, пока вы не сделали `webSocket.close`, ваше соединение открыто и вы можете в любой момент отправлять и получать сообщения.

Comment: @post_zeew спасибо, очень интересная статья

Comment: @eugeneek спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: @eugeneek Всё-таки немного не понимаю. Вот у меня есть MainActivity, в ней я создаю экземпляр класса EchoWebsocket и передаю его в client.newWebSocket. Затем если я захочу послать новое сообщение, как мне это сделать? Создать в классе EchoWebsocket  метод для отправки сообщения? Но как? Ведь для отправки сообщения надо использовать webSocket, который передаётся в методе обратного вызова onOpen, а если я создам отдельный метод, то я не смогу отправить сообщение из этого класса. Или надо как-то иначе отправлять сообщения?

Comment: @eugeneek ааа, всё, дошло! Через ws в MainActivity можно отправлять сообщения)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю что такой вопрос появился в виду непонимания что такое веб сокет. Суть его в том что связь с сервером устанавливается 1раз. Дальше все происходит в listener е если внимательно посмотришь там есть 3 основных события. OnOpen OnClose onMessage. OnOpen и OnClose это твои действия когда вебсокет открылся и когда он закрылся. Если сокет сразу закрываешься... значит сервер к которому ты хочешь присоединиться тебя выбрасывает. Те коннект не происходит в виду аутентификации и тд... onMessage это то с чем работаешь ты на прямую. Именно в нем ты получишь все Сообщения от сервера пока установлена связь. Этот пример показывает саму реализацию а не конкретно единственный подход.