# Минни мессенджер

Tags: java, android, spring, kotlin

занимаюсь android разработкой год+- пару месяцев, поднадоел.. и я начал смотреть в сторону Spring в частности REST API. И вот захотелось объединить это все в голову пришла идея для такого минни-мессенджера, начал искать информацию, и не смог найти можно ли как-то в android отслеживать изменение??

P/s поэтому пришел сюда сам пробовал работать в android с Retrofit2 и OkHttp, но их функционал(как я понял) Сделан только под получение и отправку данных

Comment: это про websockets?

Comment: Можно поподробнее,как вы видите связь двух мобильных устройств, просто не совсем понимаю причем тут ВебСокет

Comment: Retrofit совсем не для этого. Каждой задаче свои инструменты. Для миНи-мессенджера отлично подойдет Firebase Realtime Database. Там уже все придумано. https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я делал недавно чат для android и как вам уже сказали в комментариях для создания месеенджера нужно будет использовать вебсокеты. Суть в том, что приложение при старте и установлении связи с сервером будет находится в постоянной связи с сервером что позволит отслеживать любое изменение данных в режиме реального времени. Вот например как я устанавливаю соединение с сервером:

```
fun createWS() {
        val loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)


        client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(AuthToken(this))
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build()

        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(BuildConfig.CHAT_URL + getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("appl_id", "") + "/")
                .build()


        ws = client.newWebSocket(request, socketListener())
    }
```

то есть как можно увидеть из кода выше, я использую `OkHttp` и это довольно сильно облегчает жизнь. В вашем случае, нужно будет разбить общую задачу на несколько подзадач:

1. Создание серверной части: получение и выдача информации должна происходить только после прохождения клиентом аутентификации, можно использовать ключи доступа например. Серверная часть должна выдавать данные при запросе и постоянно держать канал для связи в активном состоянии.
2. Создание клиентской части: в приложении нужно реализовать возможность подключиться к серверу и получить оттуда например список контактов, после выборе контакта из списка нужно передать серверу например id выбранного контакта и дальше загрузить последние сообщения. Ну и разумеется добавить обработку отправки и получения информации от других клиентов. Суть соединения я думаю будет приблизительно такой: `клиент - сервер - клиент`

Вот есть [хорошая статья про вебсокеты](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-use-websockets-on-android-with-okhttp-ba5f00aea988), [туториал](https://trinitytuts.com/connect-to-websocket-on-android-using-okhttp/), [документация](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-web-socket/) и [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696873/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-websocket-%D0%B2-okhttp)

Comment: Еще соединения могут рваться и обработка падать, так что стороны могли бы сообщать друг-другу например lastHandledMessageSeqId

Comment: Mожно делать и гибридно с REST -- основная работа по REST, а по вебсокету только оповещения, типа ContactsWasChanged

Comment: там есть слушатели в okhttp при разрыве соединения можно слать какое-то уникальное сообщение, но вообще если соединение прерывается то там это видно сразу)

Comment: Я о том, что время жизни объектов на клиенте и сервере может не быть равным времени жизни соединения и от этого могут быть хитрые ошибки синхронизации. Это не про конкретную библиотеку или язык, а общие мысли о разработке распределенных систем.

Случаи бывают разные:
https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/442762/